# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_shape' in standard AdamOptimizer Initialization

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to construct a basic neural network in TensorFlow by following an example in *Hands-On Machine Learning* by Aurelian. The following code

```
n_inputs = 4
n_hidden = 4
n_outputs = 1
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()

learning_rate = 0.01

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs])
hidden = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, activation=tf.nn.elu,
                         kernel_initializer=initializer)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs,
                         kernel_initializer=initializer)

outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
p_left_and_right = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[outputs, 1-outputs])


action = tf.multinomial(tf.log(p_left_and_right), num_samples=1)
y = 1. - tf.to_float(action)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=y, logits=logits)
print("cross_entropy: ", cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
gradients = [grad for grad, variable in grads_and_vars]
gradient_placeholders = []
grads_and_vars_feed = []
print("grads_and_vars:", grads_and_vars)
for grad, variable in grads_and_vars:
  gradient_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=grad.get_shape())
  gradient_placeholders.append(gradient_placeholder)
  grads_and_vars_feed.append((gradient_placeholder, variable))
training_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars_feed)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

produces the error

```
cross_entropy:  Tensor("logistic_loss_15:0", shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
grads_and_vars: [(None, <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_2/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_3/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_3/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_4/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_4/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_5/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_5/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_6/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_6/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_7/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_7/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_8/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_8/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_9/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_9/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_10/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_10/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_11/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_11/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_12/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_12/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_13/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_13/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_14/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_14/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_15/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_15/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_16/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_16/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_17/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_17/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_18/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_18/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_19/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_19/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_20/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_20/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_21/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_21/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_22/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_22/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_23/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_23/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_24/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_24/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_25/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_25/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_26/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_26/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_27/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_27/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_28/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_28/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_29/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_29/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>), (<tf.Tensor 'gradients_14/dense_30/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense_30/kernel:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32_ref>), (<tf.Tensor 'gradients_14/dense_30/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense_30/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32_ref>), (<tf.Tensor 'gradients_14/dense_31/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense_31/kernel:0' shape=(4, 1) dtype=float32_ref>), (<tf.Tensor 'gradients_14/dense_31/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'dense_31/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>)]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-29-c35bfbdeba85> in <module>()
     27 print("grads_and_vars:", grads_and_vars)
     28 for grad, variable in grads_and_vars:
---> 29   gradient_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=grad.get_shape())
     30   gradient_placeholders.append(gradient_placeholder)
     31   grads_and_vars_feed.append((gradient_placeholder, variable))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

My best guess was that this had to do with passing in `None` for the first dimension of `shape`, but changing that into a number does nothing for the error. What is the cause of this?

Also, I'm relatively new to TensorFlow and this type of neural network, so don't be afraid to dumb things down. ;D

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid to be obvious but in case you miss: it says 'grad' is None. I would create a breakpoint right after you assign "grad_and_vars" and inspect it